# An application of ping-pong lemma

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $F_2$ be free group of rank two with generators $a$ and $b$. If $H$ is a subgroup of $F_2$ generated by $d\geq 2$ elements with $$H=\langle a,b^{-k}ab^k, k=1,2,...,d-1\rangle,$$ I was trying to use ping-pong lemma to show that $H$ is a free group of rank $d$. I was looking at the action of $H$ on $F_2$ via conjugation and trying to find $d$ disjoints subsets $X_1,X_2,\dots, X_d$ of $F_2$ such that if we set $g_1=a, g_k=b^{-k}ab^k, k=1,2,\dots, d-1$ and show that $g_jX_ig_j^{-1}\subseteq X_j.$ I am doing it by hit and trial but nothing seems to be working even for $d=2$.

Comment: Why don't you simply write $H=\langle b^{-k}ab^k,\; k=0,\dots,d-1\rangle$?

Comment: In any case it is true. If $A,B$ are groups, then in $A\ast B$, the subgroups $aBa^{-1}$ for $a\in  A$ generate their free product. The proof is quite immediate: consider the semidirect product $B^{\ast A}\rtimes A$ ($A$ acting by shift) and map $A\ast B$ to it in the obvious way.

Comment: The easiest and most illuminating way to prove this is to draw the Stallings core graph for the subgroup $H$.  If you're determined to use ping pong, you should think about the complementary components of the geodesic $[1,b^{d-1}]$ in the Cayley tree.

Comment: I really like how many different (yet, under the hood, the same!) answers this question attracts. It showcases just how beautiful even the most basic objects of combinatorial/geometric group theory are; so imagine how beautiful the rest of it is! :-)

Answer (score 7):

As another version of HJRW’s answer: free groups are (isomorphic to) fundamental groups of graphs.  The rank is then captured by the number of “independent” loops in the graph.  For example $F_2$ is isomorphic to the fundamental group of the rose with two petals.  Now use the correspondence between subgroups and covering spaces.

Comment: @ADL - you are correct that the covering is not finite sheeted and you are correct that the cover is thus an infinite graph.  But you are not correct that it has infinitely many loops.  Think about the cover corresponding to the trivial subgroup...

Comment: Sorry, yes, you're right - $\pi_1$ of this space corresponds to the subgroup, and as it is a $1$-complex there can only be finitely many loops! I've deleted my comment....

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to get this result from the correspondence between subgroups and covering spaces?  I’m familiar with that correspondence and some of its applications (e.g. to see that any subgroup of a free group is free), but I’m not seeing how to use it to identify the rank of the subgroup generated by some set of elements.

Comment: @SamNead: Perhaps it's worth pointing out that the 'number of "independent" loops'" is just the first Betti number, and can also be computed from the Euler characteristic.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine: You should look at Stallings' 1983 *Inventiones* paper "Topology of finite graphs". Some of the relevant ideas are also discussed in this blog post: https://ldtopology.wordpress.com/2008/12/01/in-memoriam-j-r-stallings-topology-of-finite-graphs/ .

Comment: @HJRW - That is why I put "independent" in quotes.  :)  I did think about mentioning the connection to Euler characteristic, but the combinatorial definition is not well-defined for infinite graphs... to stay combinatorial I'd've had to pass to the core, and then my answer would've turned into your answer.

Comment: @HJRW: Thanks!  The Stallings paper is lovely, and using the core graphs (or just the presentation of subgroups by *immersions*, which I wasn’t familiar with before), I see how the present result becomes an easy application.  However I still would be grateful if @ Sam Nead could elaborate what they have in mind in this answer — I don’t see how to get this from just the correspondence with covering spaces, or at least, not without needing enough analysis of the Cayley tree that you’re essentially doing [the elementary argument with reduced words](https://mathoverflow.net/a/446832) anyway.

Comment: @HJRW: I’ve written the immersions version up into [another answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/446904/2273).

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine: Thanks for doing this! The connection between the Stallings core and covering space arguments is that the immersion from the Stallings core lifts to an embedding into the covering space. (Proof: The universal cover of the Stallings core immerses into the universal cover of the covering space. But any immersion of trees is an injection. Now, since the fundamental groups are the same, this embedding descends to an embedding.) So the Stallings core really is a "core" for the covering space! (Hence the name "core".)

Answer (score 7):

**Fact.** *In a free product $A\ast B$, the groups $aBa^{-1}$ for $a\in A$ generate their free product. In other words, the homomorphism $j:B^{\ast A}\to A\ast B$ mapping $b$ in the $a$-th copy to $aba^{-1}$, is injective.*

One proof only uses the universal property of free products (already used to defined $j$). Indeed, let $A$ act in $B^{\ast A}$ by shifting and consider the semidirect product (free version of the wreath product) $A\ltimes B^{\ast A}$.

Then since $j$ is $A$-equivariant, it extends to a homomorphism $J:A\ltimes B^{\ast A}\to A\ast B$, mapping $A$ identically to the free factor $A$.

Also, by the free product universal property, there is a unique homomorphism $p:A\ast B\to A\ltimes B^{\ast A}$ which is the "identity" map on both factor ($B$ mapping onto the copy indexed by $1_A$). Then one directly sees that $p\circ J=\mathrm{id}$. So $J$ is injective. In particular $j$ is injective, which is what we had to prove. [Of course $J$ is surjective too, so $p=J^{-1}$.]

(This makes this simpler, than, for instance, the fact that subgroups of free groups are free, for which the simplest proofs are topological.)

Comment: This is very nice, and deserves to be higher, since it shows this is really simpler and more general than what’s given in the other answers.

Comment: This proof seems very similar in spirit to the proof we give in https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.0027.pdf of Nielsen-Schreier and Kurosh using wreath products, but for this particular type of subgroup the transversal arguments which complicate things are not necessary.

Answer (score 7):

(This is an elaboration of HJRW’s comments on the question and on [Sam Nead’s answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/446821/2273).)

This can be seen using the representation of free groups as fundamental groups of graphs, and subgroups as *immersions* of graphs, as developed in the very readable paper *Topology of finite graphs* (Stallings, 1983, *Inventiones*, [doi:10.1007/BF02095993](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02095993)).  Only a few facts are needed.

**Fact 1.** The fundamental group $\pi_1(G,x)$ of a graph $G$ at a vertex $x$ can be represented as the reduced cycles at $x$ (i.e. paths from $x$ to itself not containing any adjacent pair of an edge and its inverse).

**Fact 2.** This fundamental group is free on the “non-trivial cycles”.  Explicitly, given a maximal tree $T$ in $G$, a free basis of $\pi_1(G,x)$ is given by the cycles $x \to_T y \overset{e}{\to} z \to_T x$ for each edge $e$ not in $T$, where $x \to_T y$ denotes the unique path from $x$ to $y$ in $T$.

**Definition.** A graph homomorphism $f : G \to H$ is an *immersion* if it is injective on the star of each vertex of $G$ (i.e. the set of half-edges incident to that vertex).

**Fact 3.** An immersion induces an injection on fundamental groups.

Now we can draw a picture:

| Stallings graph immersion |
| --- |
| [image: Stallings immersion presentation of the OP’s graph] |

This is evidently an immersion $f : G \to H$. Fact 2 above says that $\pi_1(H,x)$ is free on the two generators $\{a,b\}$, while $\pi_1(G,x_0)$ is free on the four generators $\{a_0,\, b_1^{-1}a_1 b_1,\, \ldots,\, b_1^{-1}b_2^{-1}b_3^{-1}a_3 b_3 b_2 b_1\}$.  Those generators map $f$ to the cycles $b^{-n}ab$ for $n = 0,1,2,3$, so the image of $f$ is the subgroup generated by these elements; so by Fact 3, that subgroup of $\langle a, b \rangle$ is free.  All this easily generalises to the case with more generators.

Stallings’ notion of *core graphs*, and the associated *folding algorithm*, explain how to find representations like this in general — given an explicit finitely-generated subgroup of a free group, the folding algorithm produces a presentation of it as an immersion from a finite graph, and hence read off a free basis.

Comment: This is great! However, it seems you are taking an immersion and noting that it corresponds to the basis? A key part of Stallings' paper is his "folding" algorithm, which lets you go the other way - start with a set of words and construct an immersion. From here one can answer the question.

Comment: @ADL: Absolutely, yes — that was what my last paragraph was aiming to say; I’ve edited it to be a little more substantial.

Comment: I did wonder if that was what you meant! It is clearer now.

Answer (score 5):

While there have been many good proofs suggested in answers or comments, that are definitely the right way to do this for more general subgroups, this particular example is sufficiently straightforward that an elementary argument seems easiest.  Put $c_i=b^{-i}ab^i$ for $i\leq 0\leq d-1$.  Then $c_0,\ldots, c_{d-1}$ generate your subgroup.  I claim by induction on length that if $w$ is a nontrivial reduced word in the free group on $d$ generators $x_0,\ldots, x_{d-1}$, then evaluating that word on $c_0,\ldots, c_{d-1}$ is nontrivial.  More precisely, I claim that if the last letter of $w$ is $x_i^{\epsilon}$ with $\epsilon=\pm 1$, then $w(c_0,\ldots, c_{d-1})$ ends in $a^{\epsilon}b^{i}$.

This is clear if $w$ is a single letter.  Otherwise, by induction $w=ux_i^{\epsilon}$ where $u$ is reduced.  Since the last letter of $u$ is not $x_i^{-\epsilon}$, we deduce by induction that $u(c_0,\ldots, c_{d-1})$ ends in $a^{\pm 1}b^{j}$ with $j\neq i$ unless the last letter is $x_i^{\epsilon}$, in which case the reduced form ends in $a^{\epsilon}b^i$.   Therefore, when we multiply $u(c_0,\ldots, c_{d-1})$ by $c_i^{\epsilon}$, we either get something ending in $b^{j-i}a^{\epsilon}b^i$ with $j\neq i$ or  the reduced form of $u(c_0,\ldots, c_{d_1})c_i^\epsilon$ will end in $a^{\epsilon }a^{\epsilon}b^{i}$ as required.

Comment: If you have some paper, then drawing the Stallings core for this example is actually much easier than this!

Comment: @HJRW, I think you can even draw this core in your head without paper. But my proof is self-contained and just uses the word problem for a free group.  The proof using cores requires knowing the fundamental group of the core is this subgroup (easy) and that the fundamental group of a graph is free on the well known basis (which can either be done with van Kampen's theorem, which is harder than my argument, or by a combinatorial argument that looks like my proof saying all cancellation occurs along paths on the spanning tree). Also I could have made the proof shorter by skipping the induction

Comment: @HJRW but for a more complicated subgroup Stallings is always the way to go

Comment: This argument also has the advantage of being a very nice introduction to the type of arguments used by Nielsen.

Comment: @HJRW, is there an easier proof is Seifert-van Kampen for graphs other than using a combinatorial argument with edge paths and thatthe standard generators are essentially Nielsen reduced?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: Sorry, I accidentally added an unfinished comment. What I really want to say is that, while I agree your argument is more *elementary*, I don't agree that this is the same thing as *easy*. For the purposes of computations like this one, one should *define* free groups as the fundamental groups of graphs; SvK is only needed as one way to see that this is definition is equivalent to other definitions one might give.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda: As you know, the history of combinatorial group theory is littered with mis-steps. One of these is the fact that Stallings' techniques are *much* better than Nielsen's for working with free groups. It's a tragedy that this has been known for forty years and yet many people still learn Nielsen's techniques first, essentially for historical reasons.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: PS I think the proof of SvK for graphs that you're asking for is an immediate consequence of folding (although I'm not 100% sure, since I'm not certain where you want to use the fact that the generators are Nielsen reduced).

Comment: @HJRW Oh, absolutely; I learned free groups via graphs rather than via Nielsen (and I learnt it from Collin Bleak, a geometric group theorist), and I found that much more appealing for "peering beyond the veil" and getting to see the depths of other areas (e.g. Bass-Serre theory).

Comment: @HJRW One further way to see why Nielsen's method is a "misstep" (though I would perhaps use less heavy language) is that he was ultimately concerned with trying to solve the word problem for all groups, as is evident from the last section of his 1921 article. That this was a misstep wouldn't become apparent until 30 years later! (Even B. H. Neumann in the early 1950s announced a proof of the decidability of the word problem in all groups).

Comment: @HJRW,  how is it a consequence of folding?  I am assuming the graph is folded.  How do I know it is free in the sense of universal properties?  I can use topology to contract a spanning tree to get to a wedge and then I guess SvK is probably a little easier for a wedge, but one must do something to get that homotopies play nicely with the wedge, or one can use the covering space proof of SvK, but I don't see this as easier for graphs than spaces.  Or you can use edge paths.  It is not too difficult to show that all cancellation occurs on the spanning tree, but this is similar to my argument.

Comment: @HJRW, in any event I agree that topology is the way to go and I am a huge fan of Stallings graphs and use them in many papers.  I just wanted to point out that the elementary argument is trivial in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a proof which relies on a straighforward generalization of the [Ping Pong Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping-pong_lemma).

> **Claim 1** Let $a$ and $b$ be the transformations of the Riemann sphere $\hat{\mathbb{C}} = \mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$ defined by
> $a(z) = \frac{1}{z} + 2,\quad b(z) = z + 4$.
> Let $d \in \mathbb{N}_{> 0} \cup \{\infty\}$. Then the set $\{b^{k}ab^{-k} \,\vert\, 0 \le k  < d\}$ is the basis of a free subgroup of $\operatorname{PGL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$.

Claim 1 and its proof are a trivial adaptation of [1, Example II.B.26] which makes use of [Schottky groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schottky_group).

> *Proof of Claim 1.* Let $\mathbb{D} = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \, \vert \, \vert z \vert \le 1\}$, $\Omega_k = (\mathbb{D} + 4k) \cup (\mathbb{D} + 4k + 2)$ for $0 \le k < d$. Observe that $\gamma_k = b^ka b^{-k}$ maps
>
> - the exterior of the disk $\mathbb{D} + 4k$ onto the interior of the disk $\mathbb{D} + 4k + 2$, and
> - the interior of the disk $\mathbb{D} + 4k$ onto the exterior of the disk $\mathbb{D} + 4k + 2$.
>
> Thus $\gamma_k^m
> (\Omega_l) \subseteq \Omega_k$ for every $k \neq l$ and every $m \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$. Clearly $\Omega_k \nsubseteq \Omega_l$ if $k \neq l$. A straightforward generalization of the [Table-Tennis Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping-pong_lemma) yields the result.

Here is **another way** to answer OP's question by means of a generalized Table-Tennis Lemma. The following claim is a geometric abstraction wrapping the solution that HJRW has outlined in comments.

> **Claim 2 [1, Solution of Exercise II.b.36.i].** Let $T$ be a tree and let $\gamma_1, \dots,\gamma_d$ be  hyperbolic automorphisms of $T$ with pairwise disjoint axes. Then the subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(T)$ generated by $\gamma_1, \dots, \gamma_d$ is free on these elements.

An automorphism $\gamma$ of a tree $T$ is *hyperbolic* if it acts on $T$ without inversion, i.e, it doesn't swap the ends of an edge of $T$, and if
$\tau(\gamma) = \min_{x \in V(T)} {\bf d}(x, \gamma(x)) > 0$ where $\bf{d}$ is the usual combinatorial distance on $T$ (i.e., the reduced edge-path length) and $V(T)$ denotes the set of vertices of $T$.
If $\gamma$ is hyperbolic, then the vertices $x$ of $T$ satisfying ${\bf d}(x, \gamma(x)) = \tau(\gamma)$ are the vertices of a subgraph of $T$ which is a geodesic line called the *axis* of $\gamma$. We denote this line by $\operatorname{axis}(\gamma)$.

> *Proof of Claim 2*.
> Re-indexing the elements $\gamma_i$ if need be, we can find $x_i \in \operatorname{axis}(\gamma_i)$ for every $i \in \{1, \dots, d\}$ such that the geodesic segment joining $\gamma_1$ to $\gamma_d$ passes through the vertices $x_1, \dots, x_d$, in this order.
> Let $\Omega_i$ be the set of vertices of $T$ such that the  geodesic segment joining $x$ to $x_i$ passes through the $\gamma_i(x_i)$ or $\gamma_i^{-1}(x_i)$. It is not difficult to check that $\gamma_i^m(\Omega_j) \subseteq \Omega_i$ for every $m \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus{0}$ and $\Omega_i \nsubseteq \Omega_j$, provided that $i \neq j$. Thus the generalized Table-Tennis Lemma applies.

Let us observe that Claim 2 also answers OP's question. Indeed, multiplying the elements of $F_2$ on the left by $\gamma_i = b^i a b^{-i}$ defines a hyperbolic automorphism of the Cayley graph of $F_2$.
As $V(\operatorname{axis}(\gamma_i)) = \{b^i a^k \, \vert \, k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, Claim 2 applies.

---

[1] P. de la Harpe, "Topics in Geometric Group Theory", 2000.

Comment: You can also do ping pong on sets of reduced words. For instance,  let $A_1^\pm$ be all the reduced words beginning with $a^{\pm1}$, let $A_2^\pm$ be all the reduced words beginning with $ba^{\pm1}$, and so on... (These correspond to the complementary components of the geodesic I mentioned in my comment above.)

Comment: @HJRW Thanks, for emphasizing it. I had noticed  your above comment, which I immediately upvoted. (I have made an edit so that a part of the answer refers now explicitly to your solution).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a direct approach using the ping-pong lemma as OP originally requests, which has been gestured at in several comments but not yet offered as an answer.

Consider the action of $F = \langle a,b\rangle$ on itself by left multiplication.  Let $X_k \subseteq F$ be the set of elements which start with $b^ka$ or $b^ka^{-1}$, in their reduced word representation.  As the ping-pong lemma requires, these are disjoint; and for $j \neq k$ and $n \neq 0$, we can see that $(b^k a b^{-k})^n X_j \subseteq X_k$ by the standard multiplication of reduced words.  The claim follows.

Under the hood this is essentially the same proof as [Benjamin Steinberg’s answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/446832/2273), but the ping-pong lemma helps organise the required analysis of reduced words.